# Add TABLESAMPLE in query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My query is

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(
  SELECT *, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by (select 0)) as rn 
) as X 
where rn > 1000 
TABLESAMPLE(10 ROWS)
```

query is working fine without tablesample clause. 
How to add tablesample with given query??

Comment: try `LIMIT 10`, instead of Tablesample

Comment: @ImmersionULTD Pretty sure SQL Server doesn't have `LIMIT`

Comment: [You can't use](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189108(v=sql.105).aspx) `tablesample` on a derived table. You could use `SELECT TOP 10 * FROM (whatever) WHERE rn > 1000 ORDER BY newid()` which order randomly-ish and grab the top 10.

Comment: Yeah just found that, not sure when it was introduced.

Comment: I want to add tablesample because tablesample can take no of rows/ rows percentage

Comment: select * from ABC Tablesample (10 ROWS) working fine

Comment: From Technet:  "TABLESAMPLE cannot be applied to derived tables, tables from linked servers, and tables derived from table-valued functions, rowset functions, or OPENXML. TABLESAMPLE cannot be specified in the definition of a view or an inline table-valued function."

Answer (score 0):

Try [tsm_system_rows](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tsm-system-rows.html) that returns a number of rows instead of a percent of the records.

```
SELECT * FROM my_table TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM_ROWS(100);
```